# Having an Issue of loader on product page in magento2.4.1?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

[image]

can anyone explane me what issue can be
i am using nginx server
purchaged theme bs_eren
& magento 2.4.1
this is only happend on product page.

Comment: My friend is using same theme and just upgrade to 2.4.1, did you fix the issue ? i will be very happy if you can share the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace script with below code in your theme **gallery.phtml** file.
May be it helps.

```
Magento-Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

Please update below code:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
            "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
            "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
            "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
             "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added above code but issue not resolve..https://prnt.sc/101muaq
please help on this

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it but the approved answer is not enough.

Firstly, catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
    </arguments>
   </block>
```

- gallery.phtml

```
<?php
$images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
$mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
    return $block->isMainImage($img);
}));

if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
    $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
}

$helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
$mainImageData = $mainImage ?
    $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
    $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');

?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                 "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u bro but this was issue of js due to upgrade 2.4.0 to 2.4.1

Comment: You'r welcome. I am happy for solution. Please can you share the solution? I was curious it

Comment: That issue occurs because a gallery.phtml in my installed theme was written in old code so i replace the gallery.phtml javaScript with the default gallery.phtml javaScript & there is another solution as well you need to search on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, can you share your gallery.phtml please? :)

Comment: Please check below code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this and see if you are still experiencing the loader issue:

sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento cache:clean
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Answer by @Cengiz partly solve the issue - there is no loader but there's no Gallery either!

Any ideas how to fix it?

Magento 2.4.2

Comment: this issue generally happend with migration and 3rd party theme installation. can you tell me what you have done?